# Facebook share not working in iphone mobile browser

Tags: facebook, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

```
I am using phonegap and jquery
```

---

mobile for Facebook share link. It's working in web browser but not in mobile browser.

My share link is:

```
http://facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=&p[url]=mysitename&p[images][0]=http://mysitename/storage/information_promotion/719/4_1361103843_SeafoodPizza.jpg&p[summary]=test
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the working one url. You have to make it https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=
Also you need to make url site whit Facebook Open Graph META Tags to get the details.